# IE9 (compatibility mode) not submitting a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a bunch of `<a>`s on a html page, each associated with a `form` and want to display a 'loading' image while the form itself sumbits (which seems to take ages, but maybe this is another matter).

So I did something a bit hackish in the onclick event of those `a`s

```
frmContent = $ ( this ).nextAll ( "form" ).clone ();
$ ( "body" ).html ( "<div class='preload'><img src='./img/loading.gif' /><br/>Caricamento in corso<\/div>" );
$ ( "body" ).append(frmContent);
frmContent.submit ();
```

This seems works on both Firefox and IE9. The problem is when compatiblity mode is enabled, this doesn't work.

I also thought about using something different when the browser is recognized as IE7, like this:

```
if ( $.browser.version != "7.0" ) {
    frmContent = $ ( this ).nextAll ( "form" ).clone ();
    $ ( "body" ).html ( "<div class='preload'><img src='./img/loading.gif' /><br/>Caricamento in corso<\/div>" );
    $ ( "body" ).append(frmContent);
    frmContent.submit ();
} else {
    $ ( this ).nextAll ( "form" ).submit ();
}
```

So the preload animation isn't shown, but this defeats the purpose.

Since I can't force my users to turn off compatibility mode and since this page must also work in IE7, what's wrong with that snippet? Is there a better way to do that.

Comment: why don t you just change the visibility instead of cloning and submitting the clone. in the event hide the form show loading div (which was invisible display:none before) and submit the form.

Comment: [You can in fact force your users to turn off compatibility mode.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Add that header with a "content" value of "IE=10" or something.

Comment: @Pointry, yes, I know, when I said I can't I meant they could be using IE7

Comment: @FedericoCulloca well yes you can't do much about that :-)  It's less of a problem every day thankfully.

Comment: What is in your form? Are there some files or what? As you are saying that it loads for ages

Comment: @FAngel, no, just hidden inputs containing numbers

Comment: Have you checked if you are cloning a form (creasy assumption, but...)?

Comment: @FAngel, crazy assumption but actually Firebug tells me frmContent is an empty object. Also, in the middle of debugging (like while on a break on the `$("body").html(...` row, the form gets submitted :/

Comment: Like what Onur tried to say... if you just want to show a "loading" overlay while the form is submitting, there are much better ways to achieve this.  Yours seems verbose and obviously unreliable.

Comment: @FAngel I corrected the bit of code that gave me the wrong form, but still nothing.

Comment: Have no idea what could be wrong there. See my examples posted with the latest comment to my answer - everything works in IE7 mode if form is attached before submit. Maybe you have some JS caching issue? Also - I've added possible workaround to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append form to a body before you submit it.

```
frmContent = $ ( this ).nextAll ( "form" ).clone ();
    $ ( "body" ).html ( "<div class='preload'><img src='./img/loading.gif' /><br/>Caricamento in corso<\/div>" );
    frmContent.hide();
    $ ( "body" ).append(frmContent);
    frmContent.submit ();
```

Like a workaround. I see no reason to replace all body HTML with preload div and clone a form. You can simply hide everything before submit and append preload div:

```
    $ ( "body" ).children().hide();
    $ ( "body" ).append( $("<div class='preload'><img src='./img/loading.gif' /><br/>Caricamento in corso<\/div>") );
    $ ( this ).nextAll ("form").submit();
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that was my first attempt and it didn't work either. I'll edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: Hm. strange. I got similar problem, but form was created on the fly, not cloned.

Comment: Take a look at these examples: http://jsfiddle.net/TVdvU/2/ - form is not appened and http://jsfiddle.net/TVdvU/ - form is appened to body. I've checked this in IE9 switched to IE7 mode. When form is appened - it works great. When I submit it without append - nothing happens.

Comment: Your second example worked, thanks a lot. Anyway most of the problem was in finding the actual form to submit. It seems that on IE9 compatibility mode, children() and find() behave in different ways than other browsers.

Comment: children and find behave in a different ways in all browsers. Find will search for all nested objects. And children will search only first level